# Ext JS 4.1 - Window isn't show after hide

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I'm not able to show a window that is defined class-level after hiding it.
I need to use show & hide it whenever it's necessary.

Here's what I've tried so far:

---

**isCapsLock** Utility function for caps lock on/off handling:

```
function(e) {

    e = (e) ? e : window.event;

    var charCode = false;
    if (e.which) {
        charCode = e.which;
    } else if (e.keyCode) {
        charCode = e.keyCode;
    }

    var shifton = false;
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        shifton = e.shiftKey;
    } else if (e.modifiers) {
        shifton = !!(e.modifiers & 4);
    }

    if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122 && shifton) {
        return true;
    }

    if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90 && !shifton) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}


Ext.define('MyApp.controller.LoginController', {
    extend      : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views       : [ 'notification.CapsLockNotification' ],
    refs            : [{
       ref      : 'capsLockNotification',
       selector: 'capslocknotification'
    }],
    init        : function() {
             this.capsLockNotification = Ext.widget('capslocknotification');
             this.control({
                  'loginform #password' : {
                      keypress    : this.handleCapsLock
                   }
                 // control logic goes here
             });
    },
    handleCapsLock : function(field, eOpts) {
        var win = this.getCapsLockNotification();
        if(ExtUtil.isCapsLock(eOpts)) {
            win.show();
        } else {
            win.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show me your getCapsLockNotification() function? Also, does it shows you a warning?. I will be easier to track the error (if any) if you debug it with, let's say "firebug"

Comment: it is generated by Ext using refs.. (updated first post; added refs)

Comment: Where is ExtUtil.isCapsLock coming from? Also how are you calling handleCapsLock? If your function appears to be hiding the window correctly, can you check that win.show(); is ever hit.

Comment: it's a function that handles caps lock on/off. I added it too into first post.

Comment: You haven't mentioned how `handleCapsLock` is called. That is critical since you are evaluating `window` hide/show based on the `eOpts` that are passed. What are the `eOpts`? Are there any additional options that you are passing in `eOpts` other that the standard ones. We need to know that. Also, we also need to know how `ExtUtil.isCapsLock()` handling exceptional cases. Is that working perfectly?

Comment: `ExtUtil.isCapsLock()` is working right, I got it by console logs. Ok I also added control logic of handleCapsLock function.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the selector is returning the right component.
Make the var win global:
    handleCapsLock : function(field, eOpts) {
        win = this.getCapsLockNotification();
        if(ExtUtil.isCapsLock(eOpts)) {
            win.show();
        } else {
            win.hide();
        }
    }
And open firebug console on firefox or the developers tools console on Chrome (both with CTRL + SHIFT + J)
write in the console:
    console.info(win);
    console.info(win.$className);
check if arenot *undefined* or *null* and the classname its correct